# Show that the curve $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ form an ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

If the definition of an ellipse is the set of points $(x,y)$ such that given two focus points $F_1, F_2$ the sum of the distances from $(x,y)$ to each focus point is constant, how can one show that the curve $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1, \quad 0 < b \leq a \quad$ forms an ellipse?

The methods that I know of are to either derive the formula by considering the foci $(-c,0), (c,0)$ and the constant distance $2k$, or to set $(x,y) = (a\cos{v}, b\sin{v})$. Is there some other, relatively easy way to show that the points satisfying the equation form an ellipse?

I am asking because in a book I am reading the author states that a "direct calculation" shows that the curve indeed forms an ellipse, but I do not understand what kind of calculation this might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ and $F_1=(-c,0)$, $F_2=(c,0)$ are the two foci, then the distance of a generic point $P=(x,y)$ of the ellipse from $F_1$ is
$$
PF_1=\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+2cx+c^2+y^2}.
$$
Substituting here $y^2=b^2-{b^2\over a^2}x^2$ one gets
$$
PF_1=\sqrt{x^2+2cx+c^2+b^2-{b^2\over a^2}x^2}=
\sqrt{{c^2\over a^2}x^2+2cx+a^2}
=a+{c\over a}x.
$$
An analogous calculation gives $PF_2=a-{c\over a}x$, so that $PF_1+PF_2=2a$.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? I think the OP wanted a proof that the curve represented by the locus of points $P$ such that $F_1P+F_2P =2a$ has the equation ${x^2\over a^2} + {y^2\over b^2} =1$, not the other way round.

Comment: @AritraDas The OP wrote  that he knows how to "derive the formula by considering the foci $(−c,0)$, $(c,0)$ and the constant distance $2k$". So I presume he wanted the derivation the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a point on the curve as $(a\cos t,b\sin t)$ for a unique $t\in[0,2\pi)$. Consider the distanc from $(c,0)$, where $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(a\cos t-c)^2+(b\sin t)^2}
&=\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t-2ac\cos t+a^2-b^2+b^2\sin^2t} \\
&=\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t-2ac\cos t+a^2-b^2+b^2\sin^2t} \\
&=\sqrt{c^2\cos^2t-2ac\cos t+a^2} \\
&=|c\cos t-a| \\
&=a-c\cos t
\end{align}
Similarly, the distance from $(-c,0)$ is
$$
a+c\cos t
$$
so the sum is $2a$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a>b$. If the property is true, by symmetry the foci must be some symmetrical points $(-c,0)$ and $(c,0)$, where $c$ is so far unknown.

The squared distance to a focus is expressed by

$$(x\pm c)^2+y^2=x^2\pm2cx+c^2+b^2\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right).$$

This expression is a perfect square when the discriminant vanishes, i.e. when

$$c^2-(c^2+b^2)\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)=0$$ or $$c^2=a^2-b^2.$$

When this is the case, the sum of distances simplifies as

$$\left|a-\frac cax\right|+\left|a+\frac cax\right|=2a.$$

(The signs were taken so that the expressions inside the absolute values are positive.)